# Google Recaptcha Error (The registered key does not work with this interface.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

I am a newbie so I dont know where the error has ocurred.
I used Invisible Google Recaptcha and every syntax is correct but google is throwing me an error that The registered key does not work with this interface. Please Help

Click Here to see a pic of the error! [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsXDr.png)

Comment: The keys that you get from google, are associated with specific web site URL. That means the code that works in your production environment, won't work in QA or dev machines. You need to get new pairs of codes for those environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error when:

1. your keys are not white-listed by Google for the new Invisible reCaptcha api
2. your keys were just white-listed by Google but are not synchronized yet through all their servers
3. you didn't register your domain with the keys (you're requesting the Invisible reCaptcha api from an unregistered domain: localhost or any other)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. My issue was that I had created recaptcha keys, not "Invisible recaptcha" keys. Make sure you select the right option when creating the keys in the first place!

[image]